# How can I emulate this soulful synth sound?

Tags: sound-design

Can someone please help me to re-create the sound on the link below on a VST synth. It is supposed to be one of the presets from Sounds of Soul for the Steinberg Retrologue VST but I've looked through all the presets and can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

I think the essence of emulating it is in the chords and the effects. Probably 4 notes being played, a triad and a lower bass note. Then there is some mild plurality to the sound. That probably means some mild chorus effect and a little reverb.

As for the synth, it sounds like a saw wave, with maybe a LITTLE square mixed in. There is a gradual slope low pass filter on it since the higher frequencies are cut out, but are still subtly present. Also there is something going on right at the onset of the sound. I think there might be a ADSR envelope opening up the low pass filter very fast. So apply an ADSR envelope to the low pass filter  with a fast attack and 100% sustain.

Hopefully this helps!

EDIT: There should be two low pass filters maybe. One steady one (maybe EQ) filtering out the higher frequency. And a second one that is mapped to the ADSR that creates the quick attack sound. This one will have a steeper slope to it.

Good synth to make this sound would the free TyrellN6. Goto for all my standard subtractive synth sounds.